# SWI prolog integration with windows store apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, integration, swi-prolog

I have wrote a program in C# for user interfaces and to get user inputs. Then I want to integrate a prolog code to get that data as input to that prolog program and calculate the answer and then display that answer in c# interface.

I'm using SWI prolog and visual studio 2013.

Please give me some ideas to do my project.

Answer (score 1):

There's a SWI-Prolog - C# interface that may be useful to connect your Prolog program to your C# user interface:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.txt